# how to make free Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure?

Tags: url

I want to make free Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure from Hyper Text Transfer Protocol. if any solution your side please help me?

I developed payment gateway and its works only https and my hosting site are http .I want to https few minutes for testing purpose. how to make free Hpps for few minutes.

Comment: I am sorry, but your question does not make sense. Can you explain it differently, possibly with examples? Do you want to invent a new HTTP-related technology open to all, convert a link from one protocol to another, switch your website from HTTP to HTTPS, upgrade a HTTP connection to a HTTPS one after it has already been initiated, acquire certificates without payment...?

Comment: i developed payment gateway and it work on HTTPS .i want to check this payment gateway integration .my hosting website are not htttps . i want to few minutes  Https only for testing purpose.

Comment: So... you have `http://kumars-website.example.com` working, and you want to try to allow `https://kumars-website.example.com` to test it?

Comment: Yes. http://kumars-website.example.com working, and I want to https://kumars-website.example.com .

Comment: The easiest way to support HTTPS is https://letsencrypt.org - they have good tutorials and simplest possible installation.